# application crashes when I use a broadcast reciever

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I wanted to start a service from a Broadcast reciever which takes "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED". When I write click on the Application in eclipse and launch it It runs well. But when I launch it from emulator on which it has already been installed, the application crashes. The following are the source codes.

**AndroidManifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.android.newsreader"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/logo"
    android:theme="@style/NewsReaderStyle" >

    <receiver
        android:name=".StartupIntentReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".LoadFeedsService" ></service>

    <activity
        android:name=".NewsReaderActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ArticleActivity"
        android:theme="@style/NewsReaderStyle_NoActionBar" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>*
```

and my **BroadCast reciever** is

```
*package com.example.android.newsreader;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
public class StartupIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i("reciever", "recieved intent"+ intent);
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, LoadFeedsService.class);

    context.startService(serviceIntent);
}
 }*
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Crashes? what is the crash report in the Logcat output?

Comment: Actually..one more problem was there. my background service was fetching data from Internet and probably internet connectivity was not available till the broadcast is recieved...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your receiver code as below and try.

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".StartupIntentReceiver"
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

If the above modification is not working modify service also as below and try.

```
<service 
    android:name=".LoadFeedsService">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="testapp.BACKGROUND_SERVICE" />                
    </intent-filter>            
</service>
```

In java code of receiver modify as below.

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("testapp.BACKGROUND_SERVICE");
```

I hope it may help you.

Comment: the service started at the boot time. but actually, Iw as fetching data from internet and probably the connection is not able when the broadcast is recieved. I am figuring out ways to get connnection before my service proceeds to get data from internet..

Answer (score 0):

When your app is already installed in the emulator and u r trying to install the app again in your emaulator the installation is over ridden with the fresh installation. This procedure sometimes does cause some issues like app crashes as the new installation is not a clean build it's a overridden build. So always remember that whenever u make some big change in your code it's always better to first uninstall already existing app and then install it again.

Comment: That's not the issue. See, when I re-install the application ,it runs because the BOOT event is already broadcasted before installation and recievers are by-passed. But when I launch it from emulator, it catches the Broadcast event and gets crashed. There is some problem with Intent and Broadcast reciever I guess. I written Logs in broadcast even those are not shown on Logcat, meaning that broadsact reciever's code is not being executed